# Implementing a shake event?

Tags: c++, algorithm, pseudocode

I'm making a gui API for games and one requested feature was a shake event. Essentially an event very similar to Windows 7's Aero Shake. When the mouse is down, if it is rapidly moved back and forth uni directionally, the event is fired. I'm just not sure what type of psedocode would go into this?

Comment: Which operating systems do you target? Which gaming framework do you use, if any?

Comment: It shouldn't be platform specific, I can create timed events, get mouse position etc,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I might consider something like this:

1. always create a vector for the direction the mouse travelled on its last move
2. always keep a record of the immediate prior vector, as you gather the next vector (which means you always have two vectors to evaluate).
3. do a dot-product of the two vectors, as each mouse input arrives.  If the dot-product is positive, then ignore it.  If it is negative, then set a time value with it and store in an array tha stores perhaps up to five of these time stamps.
4. repeat the above sequence.  If the timestamp array has a consecutive set of timestamps that each differ by some epsilon, then you can presume someone is shaking something. :)

Comment: I could be wrong, but in (4) don't you mean delta, instead of epsilon?

Comment: @slomojo: by 'epsilon' I just meant a very small delta.  Given its usage in the calculus, perhaps epsilon is an over-statement. :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to count the changes in mouse movement. If mouse changes direction more than 3 times in less than, say, 0.7 seconds then it's a shake. To detect the change in direction track forever last 5 mouse coordinates. If point P0 is last, and P5 fifth to last then calculate an angle made between P0-P3 and P3-P5. If the angle is lest that 5 degrees then the mouse changed direction.

Comment: something like this will probably be the best solution. This isn't an exact science after all.

Comment: Depends on the sample size and frequency.  Every movement of the mouse can potentially generate events.  If the samples come too close together, you end up with what looks more like a curve than a sharp angle.  Particularly since few people are that good at moving the cursor in exactly the opposite direction -- the motion often rounds out a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The general idea would be something like this:

**On mouse down:**

1. Store the current position as `(x0, y0)`.
2. Set `slope = 0`.
3. Set `start time = current time`.

**On mouse move:**

1. Store the current position as `(x, y)`.
2. Set `newSlope = abs((y - y0) / (x - x0))`. (this indicates the direction of mouse movement with respect to the starting position)
3. If `abs(newSlope - slope) < some threshold` then the user is still moving in the same direction: then check if `current time - start time > shake time`, if so, fire the shake event and reset `start time`.
4. Otherwise, the user has changed direction. Set `slope = newSlope` and reset `start time = current time`.

Comment: Be careful about the off chance of someone moving the mouse exactly vertically, though -- seems to me that could easily cause a "division by zero" exception/error.

Answer (score 2):

I found more elegant and more to the point answer. Track last N (say 20) mouse positions. Those positions are bounded by rectangle whose top is minimum(P(N).top), bottom = maximum(P(N).bottom), etc. Calculate the total distance the mouse moved during those last N times. If the total distance traveled is more than K times larger than that rectangle's perimeter then it's a shake.

You may want to determine N based on time. Take only the mouse positions that are old at most 1.5 seconds, or so.